# HTML Get Request, send current variables

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to make a page and search feature, I have list by category's and username, however whenever I put a username/category and I change to the next page it resets that. How do I send a new form with all the old attributes?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: So essentially, I have a search term called order by, so lets say its ?orderby=id, then I want it to go to page 2 it would be orderby=id&page=2 but when it goes to page to it gets rid of the orderby=id and just goes to &page=2